# What is the most efficient way for purging messages with specific matches?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am coding the "purge" command for a Discord server with python library. Users would give in put in following syntax:

```
!purge <Amount> [filter] [*filter_options]
```

filter: attachments, embeds, humans, bots, startswith, endswith...
*filter_options: example: text to check with "startswith" filter

I used to have the following code (example):

```
if function == "embeds":
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount, lambda x: len(x.embeds) != 0)
```

The problem with the code is, that the amount is how many messages are checked, not the amount of matches to delete.

So coming to the point, is there an alternative for the code above, to clear an amount of matches instead of defining the amount as the number of total messages in the channel to check?

I have the following code, but this always throws a "Can only bulk delete messages up to 100 messages.", even if I set a break command when the amount (kept under 100) is reached:

```
to_purge_list = []
counter = 0
if function == "embeds":
    async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=1000, oldest_first=False):
        if counter == amount:
            break
        else:
            if len(message.embeds) != 0:
                to_purge_list.append(message.id)
                counter += 1
    await ctx.channel.delete_messages(to_purge_list)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you're posting the right code? Your question refers to a bulk delete function, and the only bulk delete code you display, you say "I used to have this"

Comment: Oh yes, I will edit it real quick. Outside the loop, under it I have the "await ctx.channel.delete_messages(to_purge_list)", which can delete up to 100 messages

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```py
limit = 100
counter = 0
to_delete = set()
async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=10000):
    counter += 1
    if len(message.embeds) == 0:
        continue
    to_delete.add(message.id)
    if len(to_delete) > limit:
        break

await ctx.channel.purge(limit=counter, check=lambda m: m.id in to_delete)
```

**I did not test this**, so I can't guarantee that it will work. It is also not super-efficient, but it works (at least the concept does).

Comment: Why use sets, message_ids are already going to be unique

Comment: @Ceres It is much faster to check `x in set()` than `x in list()`